# Series with parameters

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

In these cases, how should I proceed ?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to know about this series?

Comment: As you proceed when there is a parameter?

Comment: Terminology remark: These are so-called *power series*. Just google this term and you will find plenty of infos on the subject, in particular on how to prove the convergence.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$, the series converges to $0$.

If $x > 1$, then the series diverges since $$\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{n^2-1}x^n \to +\infty.$$

If $x = 1$, then the series diverges since $$\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{n^2-1} \sim \frac{1}{n} ~\text{and} ~ \sum_n \frac{1}{n} = +\infty.$$

If $0 < x < 1$, then the series converges since $$\frac{n+\sqrt{n}}{n^2-1}x^n \sim \frac{x^n}{n} ~\text{and} ~ \sum_n \frac{x^n}{n} = -\log(1-x).$$

For $x<0$ use the Leibniz criterion.

Comment: @b00nheT I wrote "For $x<0$ use the Leibniz criterion." at the very end of the answer